# Toggle div visibility according to scroll position and content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to achieve having simple sharing buttons on the side of a post, which are only visible if the post is within the view. So they are hidden if the user is scrolling above or below that post.

[jQuery waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) it my current weapon of choice. My approach consists of:

```
// first hiding the div
$('.post-sharing-side').hide();

// fading it in as soon as the headline reaches the top of the viewspace (that feels right in my use case)
$('.entry-title').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.post-sharing-side').fadeIn();
});

// fading it out again as soon as the upcoming div reaches the bottom of the viewspace
MISSING
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the last part: fading it out again. Ideally it should also work when scrolling up again. Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

**Update:**

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough: the effect I'm looking for is basically **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/psteinweber/ZUyRf/1/)** bit without using absolute values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way, not using jQuery waypoint at all in the end:

```
$('.post-sharing-side').hide();

var entryheight = $('.entry-content').height();

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 350 && y < entryheight) {
         $('.post-sharing-side').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.post-sharing-side').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the waypoint documentation at http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs:

> Vertical waypoints may also use the value 'bottom-in-view'. This is a
>   shortcut for a common function that sets the waypoint to trigger when
>   the bottom of the element hits the bottom of the viewport.
>
> $('.thing').waypoint({   offset: 'bottom-in-view' });

This might help.

Comment: Yes I found that, but couldn't make it work. Where does the fadeOut action go?

Comment: Thanks for the effort @theCoder - unfortunately that's not what I was looking for. The effect I'm trying to achieve is basically this but without absolute values (but with the div length): http://jsfiddle.net/psteinweber/ZUyRf/1/